# comparing two vectors, make it more efficient

Tags: c++, performance, vector

Using kcachegrind and running a code in debug mode, I have found that the bottleneck of my program is the point that two vectors are compared.

```
if (v1 == v2) {
  // DO
}
```

How can I make it more efficient? Is this better

```
if (v1[0] == v2[0]) {
   if (v1 == v2) {
      // DO
   }
}
```

The first line will filter some useless comparisons.

Before that I tried

```
if (!v2.empty())
  if (v1 == v2) 
   // DO
```

However I found that they are almost always not empty. So additional time for empty() is also included.

I have to say that the size of vectors are mostly small. 2~4 elements. in rare cases, they will extend to 10.

**UPDATE:** 
Thanks to Mats Petersson, it seems that by compiling in optimization mode, there are some more performance improvements.

Comment: what is the `value_type` of your vector?

Comment: @skp: they are uint_64t

Comment: How large are v1 and v2?

Comment: They are mostly small. 2~4 elements

Comment: @mahmood are you telling, that comparing `vector<uint_64t>`s of 2-4 elements is the bottleneck? Are you by any chance benchmarking debug build, instead of release build with optimizations turned up?

Comment: To be honest, I profiled that with kcachegrind. So I ran in debug mode.

Comment: @mahmood In C++, optimizations, especially inlining, also loop unrolling, play a big part in performance. If bottleneck is such a trivial thing, which would certainly be subject to these optimizaitons, then benchmarking a debug build is pretty pointless.

Comment: Gah! Please turn off debugging (leave debug symbols on if needed) for performance measurements.

Comment: But I had tried that when I compile in -O3 and run with kcachegrind, it can not point to the source code.

Comment: @mahmood Yeah, that can be a problem, optimizations can mangle the straightforward assembly of unoptimized build pretty throughly. I like to call this *micro-profiling uncertainity principle*: you can't get both exact location of bottleneck in original source code, and the true bottleneck in optimized code.

Comment: @mahmood but if you actually meant, there's no debug information, when you said "can not point to the source", then that's fixable, just compile with both optimization flags and debug info enabled (for gcc, `-O3 -g`). Though it can show some strange behaviour when you do that, because binary code no longer matches the source or the debug info quite 1:1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would give it a try, but I expect that the internals of `v1 == v2` turns into something like:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < v1.size && i < v2.size; i++)
 {
    if (v1[i] != v2[i])
       return false;
 }
```

[The above is probably NOT how it's actually implemented, but shown as a "it works like this"]

So, you would only barely gain something if index 0 is the most commonly different element.

By all means, try it (that would probably be quicker than asking here anyway!)

Of course, the primary part of this particular question, in view of the comments, is "Don't benchmark/profile your code with optimization turned off". It is quite easy to get 10x worse performance when measuring in the tiny details and tight loopy bits of code then the optimization is turned off [and if the "debug mode" also enables extra checks and such things to ensure no out of bounds use, etc, we can see 100-1000x slower code]

Comment: I imagine the first thing any such implementation would do is compare array sizes before looping tho :)

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right - if we are simply returning the "are they equal or not" - typically, the result is a "0 for equal, postive for V1 is greater than V2, negative for V1 is less than V2" or something like that, as it's a commmon "compare" function that performs the check.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Please add the optimization tip in your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If it’s really the bottleneck of your program, you should refactor your design. Comparing two ranges always runs in *O(N)*.

If you really want to keep your design, well, you either have the choice: keeping those performances or making surmises. You may want to look for the part of the vector that *would* change the most. Of course if you have perfectly random push_backs, it’s not worth it. Then you can start to test those elements in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The second code block is only marginally more efficient, but it is incorrect: consider what happens if one or both vectors are empty. The only saving here comes from avoiding a call overhead and a loop setup overhead when the strings differ in the first character. These savings are not worth complicating your program, because they are too small.

If you would like to make your savings more substantial, consider replacing strings with custom classes that implement equality differently: for example, you could pre-compute and store a hash code of your vector, and use element-by-element comparisons only when hash codes are different.

Answer (score 2):

Since your type is basic integer type, you may **try*** to compare them as chunk of memory using [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/)

`memcpy` gets two buffers (`void*`) and returns 0 iff buffers has equal chunks of memory

```
bool equal = v1.size() == v2.size() && memcmp(&v1.front(), &v2.front(), sizeof(v1[0]) * v1.size()) == 0;
```

(*) - I highlighted word try to show that it not necessary will help, but it's one of possibilities

Comment: You probably mean "memcmp".

Comment: I'm not convinced it's a huge amount faster tho'.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I guess if it's faster then compare 1-by-1 it should be used in `vector` but if it's bottleneck it's good idea to test it

Comment: @mahmood, I've added some info

Comment: memcmp still does a "one by one" compare, but perhaps it does use 128-bit SSE instructions, which halves the number of instructions needed. But given that the size is 2-4 elements, I doubt it's much to be gained, really.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, when I wrote it, I thought about special instructions. there was no info that vectors are so short. In this case I agree, chances that it will help is about 0

Answer (score 0):

I imagine any implementation you'd have would start with verifying that array sizes are equal and then continue with going over the elements one by one and comparing them (returning false as soon as it can - on the first difference). So your suggestion does not help by much, and neither does std::mismatch.

However, if you could keep your vectors sorted, perhaps a smarter check could be feasible. Can you?

Comment: elements are inserted randomly. So additional sorting is required.